# How to get value of variable name from python list with example

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am generating list of class variables as below and i need print the value of those variable.

```
class MYClass(object):

    a = '1'
    b = '20'
    c = 'hello'

    def as_list(self):
        return [attr for attr in dir(MYClass()) if not callable(attr) and not attr.startswith("__") and not attr == 'as_list']


c = MYClass()
print c.as_list()
```

The above code would result in ['a', 'b', 'c'] but i need the value as ['1', '20', 'hello']

Comment: Wouldn't `dir(self)` instead of `dir(MYClass())` be more appropriate?

Comment: Actually that is static method so self can't be used , for pasting here i made some minor changes to code sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are doing this, but instead of returning `attr` from your list comprehension you should return `getattr(self, attr)`.